# How could I automatically update and display time(every 10 sec) using Lift Comet

Tags: scala, lift

I am new to Liftweb. I am trying a sample on Liftweb Comet it is working fine But the time is not updating automatically in client UI(it is working fine with manually(when clicking Refresh button))

My sample code:-

HTML:-

```
<lift:comet type="Clock" name="Other">
   Current Time: <clk:time>Missing Clock</clk:time>
</lift:comet>
```

Comet:-

```
class Clock extends CometActor {
  override def defaultPrefix = Full("clk")

  def render = bind("time" -> timeSpan)

  def timeSpan = (<span id="time">
  {timeNow}
  </span>)

  // schedule a ping every 10 seconds so we redraw
  ActorPing.schedule(this, Tick, 10000L)

  override def lowPriority: PartialFunction[Any, Unit] = {
    case Tick => {
      println("Got tick " + new Date());
      partialUpdate(SetHtml("time", Text(timeNow.toString)))
      // schedule an update in 10 seconds
      ActorPing.schedule(this, Tick, 10000L)
    }
  }
}

case object Tick
```

Errors:-

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined liftAjax.js:258
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined cometAjax.js:39
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
```

Please suggest me i am strucking here

Thanks

Sandy

Comment: Did you include the js for jQuery on your page / set it to automatically include in `Boot.scala`?

Comment: I added LiftRules.jsArtifacts = JQueryArtifacts this but not working

Comment: Take a look at the answer for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20747815/uncaught-reference-error-lift-ajax-is-not-defined I believe it is the same solution for your problem.

Comment: thanks waffle paradox.........its working fine thanks

Answer (score 0):

### confirm these two steps

1. [Inject jQuery module in `Boot.scala`](https://github.com/iPrayag/moonmarket-sbt/blob/master/src/main/scala/bootstrap/liftweb/Boot.scala#L84)

   ```
   LiftRules.jsArtifacts = JQueryArtifacts
   JQueryModule.InitParam.JQuery=JQueryModule.JQuery172
   JQueryModule.init()
   ```
2. [source `jquery.js`](https://github.com/iPrayag/moonmarket-sbt/blob/master/src/main/webapp/hulaki/hulaki.html#L33)

   ```
   <script id="jquery" src="/classpath/jquery.js" type="text/javascript">
   </script>
   ```