# uncaught ReferenceError: liftAjax not defined

Tags: scala, sbt, lift

My background in Java is pretty much non-existent, and I've been reading stuff on Scala and playing on REPL for a few weeks (I do have experience with PHP). I'm just getting started trying to create a simple web server using Scala with Lift framework.

I managed to get it running (using Windows 7 x64, Java version: 1.8.0_60).

Following [this](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000000030/ch01.html#_problem_2) and [this](http://simply.liftweb.net/index-3.1.html) example, Here's what I did to get the server running from scratch:

Installed Java 1.8.0_60

Installed SBT with .msi installer

created `build.sbt`

```
organization := "org.test"
name := "testproj1"
version := "0.1-alpha"
scalaVersion := "2.11.7"
libraryDependencies ++= {
    val liftVersion = "2.6"
    Seq(
      "net.liftweb" %% "lift-webkit" % liftVersion % "compile",
      "net.liftmodules"   %% "lift-jquery-module_2.6" % "2.9",
      "org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-webapp" % "8.1.7.v20120910" % "container,test",
    )
}
enablePlugins(JettyPlugin)
```

created `project/plugins.sbt`

```
addSbtPlugin("com.earldouglas" % "xsbt-web-plugin" % "2.0.4")
```

created `project/build.properties`

```
sbt.version=0.13.8
```

created `src/main/scala/bootstrap/Boot.scala`

```
package bootstrap.liftweb

import net.liftweb._
import net.liftmodules.JQueryModule
import util._
import Helpers._

import common._
import http._
import sitemap._
import Loc._

import code.snippet._

class Boot {
  def boot {
    LiftRules.addToPackages("code")
    val entries = List(
      Menu.i("Home") / "index",
      Menu.i("DynamicTest") / "helloworld",
      Menu.i("Static") / "static" / **
    )
    LiftRules.setSiteMap(SiteMap(entries:_*))
    LiftRules.early.append(_.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"))

    LiftRules.htmlProperties.default.set(
      (r: Req) => new Html5Properties(r.userAgent)
    )

    JQueryModule.InitParam.JQuery = JQueryModule.JQuery21Z
    JQueryModule.init()
  }
}
```

created `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml`:

```
<web-app>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>LiftFilter</filter-name>
    <display-name>Lift Filter</display-name>
    <description>The Filter that intercepts Lift calls</description>
    <filter-class>net.liftweb.http.LiftFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>LiftFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Then in `cmd`, I ran `sbt`, updated, then start server with `jetty:start`.

Everything seems to work fine. I can do simple static pages and sitemapping. However, when I try to use Ajax, I get a JS error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: liftajax is not defined

What I'm trying to do is just a simple content replacement using `ajaxcall()`. Here's what I have for my helloworld.html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type" />
    <title>Dynamic</title>
  </head>
  <body class="lift:content_id=main">

    <p>Bello!</p>
    <div id="main" class="lift:surround?with=default;at=content">
      <script id="jquery" src="/classpath/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      This page has dynamic content.
      <div data-lift="HelloWorld">
        <input id="name-input" placeholder="put your name here">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit Name">
        Hello, my dear <span id="name"></span> :)
      </div>
    </div>
    <p>Bubbai</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here's my `src/main/scala/code/HelloWorld.scala`

```
package code.snippet

import net.liftweb._
import util.Helpers._
import http.js._; import JE._; import JsCmds._
import http.SHtml._


class HelloWorld {
  def render = ":submit [onclick]" #> ajaxCall(
    ValById("name-input"), 
    n => SetValById("name", n)
  )
}
```

(I do notice that if I put the script tag in the `<head>` of the html file, it doesn't get included). What I do get from the browser is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<div id="main">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/classpath/jquery.js" id="jquery"></script>
  This page has dynamic content.
  <div>
    <input placeholder="put your name here" id="name-input">
    <input onclick="liftAjax.lift_ajaxHandler('F461833963092XQOEYM=' + encodeURIComponent((function() {if (document.getElementById(&quot;name-input&quot;)) {return document.getElementById(&quot;name-input&quot;).value;} else {return null;}})()), null, null, null)"
    value="Submit Name" type="submit">Hello, <span id="name"></span> :)
  </div>
</div>
```

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20747815/uncaught-reference-error-lift-ajax-is-not-defined?s=1%7C0.3687). The answer there told me to get the JQuery module up and running, which I did. The jQuery file is loaded. But of course the `liftajax` in `onclick` is not defined anywhere.

So the main question is, where should the `liftajax` be coming from, and what am I missing to get this running? Thanks.